# How do I restrict access to all ports with source's PublicKey like SSH does?

Tags: linux, networking, port, ubuntu-18.04, ssl-certificate

I want a server to block any and all incoming traffic on all ports with the exception of the traffic from those machines which can be (and are right there and then regardless of the port being accessed eg 443, etc) authenticated using the same (or similar with similar or better security) mechanism as PublicKey-PrivateKey SSH connections. I really don't know how to put this any better, feel free to ask for any specific details if needed.

Comment: What's the purpose? Is this for a server or a workstation? Are those other machines also regular PCs/servers, or are they mobile devices?

Comment: Security. Simple as that. It's a server. Those machines are regular PCs, Mobiles and potentially other servers too.

Comment: What do you mean by "machine is right there"? What version of Linux?  How does the server get its IP address?  In general terms you need 2 different tools to do this. You can restrict access based on IP using a firewall (ie iptables or a wrapper - how typically depends on OS). You might be able to remove the default gateway as well/instead if its limited to LAN. This will solve the IP/physical access restriction part....

Comment: To solve the "all connection encrypted like SSH part" it depends on the protocol. If you want all protocols encrypted you would need to run a VPN server on the box and a VPN client on each client that can access the server. You wpuld also need a VPN which does public/private encryption. OpenVPN can do all of this.  (You would also need to firewall access to OpenVPN only). This is a fairly advanced setup.

Comment: @user1686 One thing I forgot to mention, no need to worry about there being too many machines, they are limited and unchanging enough that PublicKeys can be acquired for all.

Comment: @davidgo My bad, that "right there and then" part was just a phrase meaning that I want the authentication by PrivateKey by asking password or similar methods to happen as soon as someone tries to even connect, same as SSH. By version do you mean this: Ubuntu 18.04. The server's IP address is static. The problem with restricting by IP is that the machines connecting to it don't have their own static IPs and since they're not in the same network, MAC addresses are a no go as well. Although if there is any other way than IPs, MAC Addresses and Key pairs then I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @davidgo I'm all good with advanced setups, basically meaning I'll go slow as a turtle but I'll get there. Just one question, I don't know how OpenVPN works, does it involve any intermediate (third party) servers? Also, if OpenVPN can do all of this then why did you mention restriction by IP earlier, does it not do something that needs additional restriction? I mean like how simple Key Pair based SSH does the job of restriction simply by telling that you don't have the right PrivateKey, OpenVPN won't cover that? Or does that mean that that kind of SSH leaves something "open" too?

Comment: You have a steep learning curve ahead. The solution is to use iptables or firewalls on the server to allow only connection across OpenVPN (and optionally  SSH). You then needs to set up OpenVPN using PKI (private key infrastructure) and deploy the OpenVPN server on your server. You need to deploy OpenVPN clients on each client with access to the server, alongside appropriate configuration files.

Comment: OpenVPN does NOT require any intermediary servers, it just requires your server is reachable (ideally on a static IP, but can be via DNS lookup).  You need to restrict access on the server toIP addresses associated with the VPN - eachvcluent will get there own RFC1918 IP from the server. You can ignore what I said about removing default route, your clarification meant it did not apply.

Comment: I'm all about the curves baby! I suppose it might be complicated in practice but it sounds so simple it should be at least given an introduction in basic server security guides, or maybe you just know how to explain well! Just to be sure though, there isn't any other way to do this with iptables, PKI and a little bit of salt?